# Round off list values in Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

```
    column1                      column2
0   name1                       [(0, 0.12561743), (1, 0.12500079), (2, 0.1250000)]
1   name2                       [(0, 0.1251732), (1, 0.12597172), (2, 0.623854998)]
```

How can I round off the values in column2 in 3 decimal places like this:

```
    column1                      column2
0   name1                       [(0, 0.125), (1, 0.125), (2, 0.125)]
1   name2                       [(0, 0.125), (1, 0.125), (2, 0.623)]
```

The following is not working as the values are in list:

```
df.column2 =  df.column2.apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop twice:

```
# don't use .column2 to assign
df['column2'] =  df.column2.apply(lambda x: [tuple(round(z, 3) for z in y) for y in x])
```

Output:

```
  column1                               column2
0   name1  [(0, 0.126), (1, 0.125), (2, 0.125)]
1   name2  [(0, 0.125), (1, 0.126), (2, 0.624)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A **list** comprehension in `apply()` works

```
import ast
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    column1                      column2
0   name1                       [(0, 0.12561743), (1, 0.12500079), (2, 0.1250000)]
1   name2                       [(0, 0.1251732), (1, 0.12597172), (2, 0.623854998)]"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df.column2 = df.column2.apply(ast.literal_eval)

df.column2 = df.column2.apply(lambda x: [(t[0], round(t[1],3)) for t in x])
```

#### output

|  | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name1 | [(0, 0.126), (1, 0.125), (2, 0.125)] |
| 1 | name2 | [(0, 0.125), (1, 0.126), (2, 0.624)] |