# pandas round to neareast custom list

Tags: python, pandas

My question is very similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712176/round-off-list-values-in-pandas-column), except I would like to round to closest, instead of always round up, so cut() doesn't seem to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.Series([11,16,21, 125])
rounding_logic = pd.Series([15, 20, 100])
labels = rounding_logic.tolist()
rounding_logic = pd.Series([-np.inf]).append(rounding_logic) # add infinity as leftmost edge

pd.cut(df, rounding_logic, labels=labels).fillna(rounding_logic.iloc[-1])
```

The result is [15,20,100,100], but I'd like [15,15,20,100], since 16 is closest to 15 and 21 closest to 20.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [pandas.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction=nearest`

```py
out = pd.merge_asof(df.rename('1'), rounding_logic.rename('2'),
                    left_on='1',
                    right_on='2',
                    direction='nearest')
```

```
print(out)

     1    2
0   11   15
1   16   15
2   21   20
3  125  100
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the absolute difference for the values, and take minimum value from `rounding_logic`:

```py
>>> rounding_logic.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
>>> df.apply(lambda x: rounding_logic[rounding_logic.sub(x).abs().idxmin()])

0     15.0
1     15.0
2     20.0
3    100.0
dtype: float64
```

PS: You need to reset the index in `rounding_logic` cause you have duplicate index after adding `-inf` to the start of the series.